# How to parse grouped text data in R and convert to data frame / time series

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, time-series

I spent a lot of time trying to parse text from a data API outputting stock ticker data in groups contained within curly braces, data format as below :

```
/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    BID = 600
    ASK = 605
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:47:48.000
}

/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    BID = 608
    ASK = 610
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:47:49.000
}

/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    BID = 602
    ASK = 605
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:47:50.000
}
```

I tried the following to parse by line but can't seem to find a way to convert this text into a table:

```
rawData <- readLines(paste (filepath, filename, sep="/"))
DataTab <- data.table(txt = rawData[!grepl(pattern = '\\/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:', rawData)])
```

The end result I would like to see is :

```
BID ASK BID_ASK_TIME 
600 605 09:47:48.000
608 610 09:47:49.000
602 605 09:47:50.000
```

This is the first time i request help here, please feel free to comment if my question is not clear.

Thanks a lot for your help !

PS : The actual data looks like this in the original "less well behaved" sample :

```
/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    BID = 600
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:50:48.000
}

/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    ASK = 610
    LAST_PRICE = 610
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:50:49.000
}

/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    ASK = 605
    LAST_PRICE = 610    
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:50:50.000
}

/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:
MarketDataEvents = {
    BID = 599
    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:51:05.000
    LAST_PRICE = 601
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep only the lines where you have a specific pattern in the text. Here, I have kept lines where a word followed by `=` and a number, put them in a matrix and convert it to dataframe.

I have used pipes (`%>%`) for readability.

```
library(magrittr)

rawData <- readLines(paste(filepath, filename, sep="/"))

matrix(grep('\\w+ = \\d+', rawData, value = TRUE), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) %>%
  sub('.*=\\s', '', .) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  setNames(c('BID', 'ASK', 'BID_ASK_TIME')) -> DataTab

DataTab

#  BID ASK BID_ASK_TIME
#1 600 605 09:47:48.000
#2 608 610 09:47:49.000
#3 602 605 09:47:50.000
```

---

For the updated dataset we can find the position of `{` and `}` and create a sequence between them. Using regex we extract the data between them and bind all of them in one dataframe.

```
rawData <- readLines(paste (filepath, filename, sep="/"))
open <- grep('{', rawData, fixed = TRUE)
close <- grep('}', rawData, fixed = TRUE)

dplyr::bind_rows(Map(function(x, y) {
  tmp <- stringr::str_match(rawData[x:y], '(\\w+) = (.*)') 
  setNames(data.frame(t(tmp[, 3])), tmp[, 2])
}, open + 1, close-1)) -> result


result

#   BID BID_ASK_TIME  ASK LAST_PRICE
#1  600 09:50:48.000 <NA>       <NA>
#2 <NA> 09:50:49.000  610        610
#3 <NA> 09:50:50.000  605        610
#4  599 09:51:05.000 <NA>        601
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it totally solves the simplified version. In reality, the data is a little less well behaved as is will randomly have more or fewer fields, and only bid or ask will be displayed in a group within `{...}`
The data looks more like :
`/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:`
`MarketDataEvents = {`
`    BID = 600`
`    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:47:48.000`
`}`

`/mktdata/ticker/AAA ?fields=ASK,BID:`
`MarketDataEvents = {`
`    ASK = 610`
`    LAST_PRICE = 610`
`    BID_ASK_TIME = 09:47:49.000`
`}`

Comment: Without an actual example of your data it would be difficult to help. Can you somehow share your text file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and effort, I attached a sample file to the original post.

Comment: Is that any different than the file that you shared earlier? Looks same to me.

Comment: Hi Ronak, the fields between {..} can be different for each instance, for example, the first update packet only had "BID" and "BID_ASK_TIME" while the next update featured "ASK", "LAST_PRICE" and "BID_ASK_PRICE"

Comment: @SMA Can you check the updated answer if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this does the trick, I just need a bit of time to digest how you combined the regex with the wrangling stuff. Cheers